# EF 6.0 - Updating Relationship with EntityState.Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In an ASP.NET MVC5 application with the following (simplified) models:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Reseller Reseller { get; set; }  
}
```

```cs
public class Reseller
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to update which Reseller the customer is associated with. When attempting to update the Customer entity by marking it as Modified (`ctx.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified`), all the columns are updated except for the CompanyID of the Reseller. It is my understanding that `Modified` marks all fields as dirty and updates all of them, but this isn't happening here.

Below is the controller action for updating the Customer. I have checked and the correct CompanyID of the Reseller is set correctly in the incoming model:

[image: VS Debugger showing the ID set correctly that should be updated in the Database]

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DbContext())
        {
            ctx.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Info", new { id = customer.CustomerID });
        }
    }

    return View(customer);
}
```

When calling SaveChanges, the following SQL is generated. Note the Reseller CompanyID is not included in the query:

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]
SET [Name] = @0, [PrimaryContact] = @1, [Email] = @2, [PhoneNumber] = @3
WHERE ([CustomerID] = @4)

-- @0: 'Sample Customer iuhiuhi' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @1: 'Joe Bloggs' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @2: 'example@example.com' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @3: '123456789' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @4: 'e4b9e8d3-9f92-e811-baa4-3052cb3d0eb2' (Type = Guid)
```

Even though it is part of the customer entity.

Comment: `CompanyID` is primary key so you can not updated it.

Comment: I don't want to change `CompanyID` - I want to update the Customer to have a different `CompanyID`

Comment: Setting state as modified only affects scalar properties, not navigation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ResellerId to Customer Model

```cs
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid ResellerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ResellerId")]
    public Reseller Reseller { get; set; }  
}
```

then change the ResellerId